# C# Move AppSettings from .exe.config in Program Folder to Custom Location

Tags: c#, appsettings

C# MVVM project targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2 with underlying SQL Server database.

We have a handful of user-writable settings in appSettings.  These are stored in the PROGRAMNAME.exe.config in C:\Program Files\PROGRAMNAME

The problem is that our users typically do not have write permissions to the C:\Program Files\PROGRAMNAME directory and so cannot write changes to this file.  The program either needs to be run as an administrator or we need to give write permissions to that directory.  Neither is ideal.

I was under the impression that it should create a copy of the .exe.config in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\PROGRAMNAME but this does not seem to happen, especially in our Citrix environments.

Is there a way to relocate these specific appSettings to a file in a user-writable location?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://codedocu.com/Net-Framework/WPF/Basics/Settings/WPF_colon_-Create,-write-and-read-settings-dynamically?2045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it. Read the config file like this:

```
Configuration App_Config = 
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("C:\Temp\PROGRAMNAME.exe");
```

By this, it will look for the config file `PROGRAMNAME.exe.config` in the specified path `C:\Temp`

Please notice the path is not specified as `C:\Temp\PROGRAMNAME.exe.config`

Get more info from [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#overloads)